# Awk: match a line number to an ending regex pattern

Tags: awk, range

How do I have awk match a line number at the start of a match and end the match at a pattern?

I tried using `1` and the end pattern of `/end/` and this fails:

```
$ echo -e 'a\nb\nc\nend\ne\nf\ng\n' |awk '1,/end/ {print $0}'
a
b
c
end
e
f
g
```

But an all pattern approach works:

```
$ echo -e 'a\nb\nc\nend\ne\nf\ng\n' |awk '/b/,/end/ {print $0}'
b
c
end
```

The question: how to use a line number at the beginning of a range?

Comment: So you want to print it from a to till string end? Please confirm once, thank you

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description, no images, no links) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: I think you are looking for `awk '1; /end/{exit}'` or `sed '/end/q'`

Comment: We don't understand your English. Please post an example of input and the corresponding output you want, as Cyrus suggests above.

Comment: If your question is "How to get a range of lines from a begin pattern (`b`) to an end pattern (`end`) using awk", then the answer is `awk '/b/,/end/' input.txt`, as you suggest.

Comment: But if your question is "How to get a range of lines from the beginning of the input to an end pattern (`end`) using awk", then the answer is `awk '(NR==1),/end/' input.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
echo -e 'a\nb\nc\nend\ne\nf\ng\n' | awk '(NR == 1),/end/'
```

Comment: I stronlgy suggest you to reformulate your question in understandable English.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't have a start condition you can just use

```
$ awk '1; /end/{exit}'
```

perhaps easier with `sed`

```
$ sed '/end/q'
```

Answer (score 0):

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/zx6FK1):

```
echo -e 'a\nb\nc\nend\ne\nf\ng\n' | awk 'BEGIN{f=1} {if(f) print} /end/{f=0}'
```

*Details*:

- `BEGIN{f=1}` - sets `f` flag to `1` (to print the lines found)
- `{if(f) print}` - if `f` is not `0` print the line
- `/end/{f=0}` - once `end` pattern is found, stop printing lines (the above condition will fail).